# Nest input inside f.label ( rails form generation )

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, label

I want to use the f.label method to create my form element labels, however - i want to have the form element nested inside the label. Is this possible?

-- From W3C --

> To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. In this case, the LABEL may only contain one control element. The label itself may be positioned before or after the associated control.
>
> In this example, we implicitly associate two labels with two text input controls:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
 <p>
  <label>
     First Name
     <input type="text" name="firstname" />
  </label>
  <label>
     <input type="text" name="lastname" />
     Last Name
  </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can nest your form helper inside of a label using a block. Here is an example using HAML, but it also works with ERB.

```
= form_for your_resource do |f|
  = f.label :first_name do
    = f.text_field :first_name
```

Comment: Works for Rails 3 (3.2.9) without HAML (plain erb).

Answer (score 11):

As Dan Garland above mentioned previously, you can definitely nest inputs inside labels with a simple block.  I'm providing this answer as an example using ERB and specifically to show exactly how you have to get [Bootstrap button groups to work like radio buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) as they require this nesting.  It took me a while to figure out, so hopefully this will help someone else.

For this example (Rails 4.2), the button group lets a user select between 3 different distance options:

```
<%= form_for(@location) do |f| %>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :distance %><br>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <%= f.label :distance, class: "btn btn-primary active" do %>
        <%= f.radio_button :distance, 0.3, checked: true %>
        0.3 miles
      <% end %>
      <%= f.label :distance, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <%= f.radio_button :distance, 0.5 %>
        0.5 miles
      <% end %>
      <%= f.label :distance, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <%= f.radio_button :distance, 1 %>
        1 mile
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit Location", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

P.S. I can't yet post screenshots to show what this looks like, but once I get enough rep points, I will.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a custom FormBuilder to allow the label helper to accept a block. It's as simple as this:

```
class SmartLabelFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def label(method, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = {}, &block)
    if !block_given?
      super(method, content_or_options_with_block, options)
    else
      options = content_or_options_with_block.is_a?(Hash) ? content_or_options_with_block.stringify_keys : {}

      @template.content_tag(:label, options, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use your form builder like this:

```
<% form_for(@article, :builder => SmartLabelFormBuilder) do |form| %>
  <% form.label(:title) do %>
    Title
    <%= form.text_field(:title) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wraps well, but it's not outputting the `for` attribute that, as I understand it, the normal helper does. That is, when I say `<% form.label(:title) %>` it outputs `<label for="title">`, but when I add the block, it just outputs `<label>` no matter what I seem to do. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BenSaufley: The for attribute is not required when the label wraps the input element. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Use this little workaround

```
<%= f.label(:content, "#{f.check_box(:allow_posts)}\n#{:content}\n".html_safe, :class => "checkbox") %>
```

will give you this

```
<label class="checkbox" for="pages_content"><input name="pages[allow_posts]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="pages_allow_posts" name="pages[allow_posts]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

content

Comment: Sorry I thought this was asking about checkboxes getting wrapped in label tags

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible using the built-in Rails' `label` or `label_tag` helpers because they don't take a block. However, if you want nesting then why wouldn't you just use the HTML element directly?—

```
<label>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
</label>
```

Comment: only because i want to take advantage of the automation of rails' label

Comment: The Rails' helper assigns the value of the input element's ID attribute to the label element's `for` attribute. It's not particularly sophisticated. Whether you use the Rails' helper or nest the input element within the label, the effect is the same; clicking the label in the browser sets the focus to the input element.

Comment: This strikes me as a massive oversight in Rails, and I'm really surprised this hasn't been addressed.  At least we have people like Tim Riley to help us fix the problem.

Comment: I'm using an older version of Rails. This worked form me as sometimes the "helpers" get in the way and it is just easier to code the HTML you want/need, rather than trying to coerce Rails to let you do what you want.