# Rails, label with nested HTML using FormBuilder and Devise, with Bootstrap markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, twitter-bootstrap, markup

I am working on the front-end part of a Rails 3.1 application. We are using a Twitter Bootstrap as CSS Framework, Devise as the authentication manager and the I18n gem for localization.

This is the devise syntax for a checkbox with its label

```
<%= f.label :remember_me %>
<%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
```

And this of course is the generated HTML

```
<label for="user_remember_me">Ricordati di me</label>
<input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Since Bootstrap adds this rule for the labels `display: block`, the label and the checkbox are not in the same line. To have the on the same line I need an HTML output like this

```
<label for="user_remember_me">
    Ricordati di me
    <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
</label>
```

As shown in the [forms markup documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

You will have noticed that the label text is in Italian, the team member who provided localization for Devised worked hard to find out how to do so, and I do not want to force he to work on it again introducing new localized strings.

I am aware of the nice fact that the `FormBuidler` `label` method accepts a block as an argument so I could do

```
<% f.label :remeber_me do %>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
<% end %>
```

But this produce an HTML output **whitout** the label! o.O
To be specific this is what I get:

```
<input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

I tried to look in the source code, the [`f.label` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/defb751681640e11f2187439acdaaa12ca9b805f/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1313) calls the [`label` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/defb751681640e11f2187439acdaaa12ca9b805f/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L658), but I can only see that if there is a block no text will be printed and that the label and block will be rendered by the `label_tag` of the `template_object`.

Before diving into a source code digging, and a no sleep night, I decided to wait a moment and ask the lifesafer community of StackOverflow for help.

Am I missing something? I am calling `f.label` with block in the wrong way? Is some parameter missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: I had the same problem with bootstrap.  I ended up just making a css rule to override bootstrap:  label { display: inline-block; }   maybe not the most elegant solution, but it worked.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457167/nest-input-inside-f-label-rails-form-generation

Maybe can be useful ;)

Comment: @Mattyx yes thanks, I already knew that question. But it's old and says that rails form does not support blocks, which is false in Rails 3.1. Plus I hoped to be able to do it with vanilla Rails syntax

Comment: @kclair :) I thought that too, but I hoped not to have to tweak it

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you ever got this working...

Running on Rails 3.2.6 this is what I had to do:

```
<%= f.label :remember_me do %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  Remember Me?
<% end %>
```

I hope that helps you since I came here looking for an answer to the exact same problem and couldn't find it, except through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the label and checkbox on the same line, you must include .form-inline in your

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <label for="user_remember_me">Ricordati di me</label>
  <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
  <input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/66TJY/

```
<%= form_tag( :class => "form-inline") %>
```