# Put input into label

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to have this result:

```
<div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
</div>
```

Notice the input in the label.
My ERB code now:

```
<div class="form-check">
   <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "form-check-label" %>
   <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "form-check-input" %>
</div>
```

How would you change this to get the input in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do. You can nest the input with a `do` block

```
<div class="form-check">
  <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "form-check-label" do %>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "form-check-input" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the label a block like so:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "form-check-label" %>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "form-check-input" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457167/nest-input-inside-f-label-rails-form-generation) for more details.

Comment: I didn't see his answer when I answered..also I linked to helpful SO question